# Why would someone create an OpenPGP public key with my name and email address?

Tags: pgp, spoofing

By chance, I typed `gpg2 --search myemailaddress` on the command line, and searched public keyservers for my email address (I'd actually just meant to search my local keyring, for which I should have used `gpg2 -k myemailaddress`).

To my surprise, I discovered that there was a public key, created just a few days ago, which as far as I know I did not create. It wasn't on my local keyring, or on the keyrings of other computers on which I've ever used GPG.

I'm at a loss how this may have happened. Are there any applications that would "helpfully" create OpenPGP keys and publish them, without telling me or attaching them to my local keychain? Is there some scam for which this would be useful?

Answer (score 4):

GPG can upload your public key automatically, and there may be other utilities that do so. The thing to do is compare the public key on the web with the one on your keyring. If they match then it **must** have originated from your system as nobody could create it in isolation (that's the whole point of public private key pairs).

If the public key is different from the one you generated then it's possible that someone is attempting to use your identity. It seems pretty unlikely though, so I'd look for other explanations.

Comment: It definitely doesn't match the keys on my keyring. Different fingerprint, different creation date, different key size. Curiously, though, it uses my full name, as does the key I produced and published -- I rarely spell out my middle name, but I did so on the recommendation that it match the name on my government-issued ID exactly. Also, looking for other explanations is kinda why I'm here.

Answer (score 3):

OpenPGP key pairs do not have the same built-in trust chain as X509 key pairs (certificates).

OpenPGP keys *can* be signed in a [Web-of-Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) manner but this is not as strongly encouraged as the hierarchical trust chain of X509 certificates, where self-signed certs have to jump great hurdles to be recognised in browsers, email clients and PDF readers.

Put simply, there is no practical way to ensure no one publishes a OpenPGP key pair with the same metadata. It simply comes down to trust; or more specifically that no one should take key meta data on face value.

---

***Why*** would someone publish a key with the same meta data?

Well, how well known is your email address? Would someone assume they are communicating with you if they saw a public key with your name or email address?

I'm assuming unless you are journalist or a [politically exposed person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politically_exposed_person), this was probably some application or website thinking it was doing you a favour - perhaps for an app feature or website service you never ended up using. It might never have even stated that it would do so - as it assumed you'd use the service sufficiently to become aware of this "feature".

As `GdD` mentions, this might be also some background PGP-aware application auto-posting a key pair that wasn't cached correctly in your primary keystore.

Comment: GnuPG isn't configured to automatically publish keys on my systems. Are you aware of any other applications that would generate keys and publish them?

Comment: @bgvaughan Is your system Windows or *Nix based?

Comment: My main desktop dual-boots Fedora 19 and Windows 7; I haven't installed anything related  to OpenPGP on Windows. At work, I have a Fedora VM running on a Windows 8 host; similarly, there aren't any OpenPGP tools that I know of on the host OS. I've also used GnuPrivacyGuard on my Android phone,  but that's not been installed for weeks. My master signing key is not stored on any of my computers. The mystery key was self-signed. And I'm pretty sure that on the day the mystery key was generated, my computer was only active for a few hours, in Windows, for gaming purposes.

Comment: @bgvaughan Hmm. Both *Nix OSes could be PGP-aware. The release of the mystery key would only need your email address, probably a pretty common piece of meta data floating around your computer and especially your mobile. It is also possible that the public key was released indirectly from `PC/Mobile -> 3rd Party -> PGP Directory Server` and so the timestamp of the key on the directory server may not reflect the initial release of it from your computer. In fact, now I think about it, any website you have used could generate a PGP key with your email address as "helpful" feature of their service.

Comment: Anyone who knows about OpenPGP and knows my (public and freely shared) email address could have created and published that public key; it wouldn't take much effort to write a shell script to scrape email addresses and create bogus public keys. The part that has me at a loss is why anyone would bother.

Comment: @bgvaughan Which is why I'm assuming unless you are journalist or a [politically exposed person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politically_exposed_person), this was probably some application or website thinking it was doing you a favour - perhaps for an app feature or website service you never ended up using. It might never have even stated that it would do so - as it assumed you'd use the service sufficiently to become aware of this "feature".

Comment: That'd make sense, but I've been hammering on search engines for hours, looking for any complaints about an application or service doing such a thing, and found nothing. My best guess is some co-worker did this to be "helpful" and hasn't gotten around to telling me.

Comment: @bgvaughan I've added some of my comments to the main answer. Good luck finding which app/website did it :-) I myself download/use about 30 - 50 *"I'll try this out"* applications per month.